# How to scrape description of every link

Tags: python, scrapy

After i useed scrapy in python and i have all url links of my products from one site, how can i acces every link and scrape description of every product?
This is my code:

```
    import scrapy


class aldi2(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'aldi2'
    start_urls = ['https://www.aldi.nl/producten/brood-bakkerij/dagvers-brood.html']

    def parse(self,response):
        for products in response.css('div.mod.mod-article-tile.mod-article-tile--default.ct-backwaren'):
            yield{
                'name':products.css('span.mod-article-tile__title::text').get().replace('\n','').replace('\t',''),
                'price':products.css('span.price__wrapper::text').get().replace('\n','').replace('\t',''),
                'unit' :products.css('span.price__unit::text').get().replace('\n',''),
                'link' : products.css ('a.mod-article-tile__action').attrib['href']
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'response.follow' or 'scrapy.Request' (but you'll need to add the base url) with the desired url.

(I changed the 'replace' function with 'strip').

```
import scrapy


class aldi2(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'aldi2'
    start_urls = ['https://www.aldi.nl/producten/brood-bakkerij/dagvers-brood.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        for products in response.css('div.mod.mod-article-tile.mod-article-tile--default.ct-backwaren'):
            yield{
                'name':products.css('span.mod-article-tile__title::text').get().strip(),
                'price':products.css('span.price__wrapper::text').get().strip(),
                'unit':products.css('span.price__unit::text').get().strip(),
                'link': products.css('a.mod-article-tile__action').attrib['href']
            }
            url = products.css('a.mod-article-tile__action').attrib['href']
            yield response.follow(url=url, callback=self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. And now if i want to acces every link from "URL" and extract every description of every product?

Comment: Then do it in the 'parse_page' function